# What support does Google search have for HTML 5?

Tags: seo, html, google-search

I'm wondering if Google search is aware of tags such as `<nav>`, `<aside>`, `<section>`, etc. that are being added by HTML 5?

My navigation comes before my content and I have too many links in it for good SEO. I'd like to use `<nav>` if Google recognised it rather than using js or a css work around.

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: it's <nav>, not <navigation>  it's <aside>, not <a-side>  it's <section>, not <content> [can sombody please edit the question!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 tags like  even now, see [Mads Kjaer article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/). Don't wait for google to be ready, use it now!

But until Google recognises those tags stick to following current SEO rules. Move your content to the beginning of the code and navigation to the end!

Comment: Google now recognizes those tags, and has for awhile. (For anyone reading this now, seeing as how it was posted years ago)

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing yet, since I don't believe any of those tags are implemented right now, and HTML5 is far from being a standard yet.

Answer (score -1):

Has this now changed? Is it safe to add HTML5  to the start of the page and not impact SEO? Is google 'aware' of these tags?